# iOS Google map SDK: Setting maxZoom level issue

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I notice when I set the max Zoom level of example to 19, the zoom go up to 20. I don't know why.
It's always 1 more zoom level than the one I set.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:23.589571946369546
                                                        longitude:58.14204730042655
                                                             zoom:16];

self.mapView_.camera=camera;
self.mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;


self.mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
self.mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
[self.mapView_ setMinZoom:5 maxZoom:19];



// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.168520, 58.008163);

marker.map = self.mapView_;
// ------ add layer
// Implement GMSTileURLConstructor
// Returns a Tile based on the x,y,zoom coordinates, and the requested floor
GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/%tu/%tu/%tu.png", zoom, x, y];
    NSLog(@"url=%@",url);
    return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you find out the maxZoom is 20? Which version of iOS Maps SDK you use?

I tried the sample [hello map application](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-ios) from Google Maps' Github page with iOS Maps SDK version 1.9.1 and put the below code in the videDidLoad() method. It prints the correct max zoom which is 19.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:23.589571946369546
                                                            longitude:58.14204730042655
                                                                 zoom:16];

    mapView_.camera=camera;
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;

    // Create the GMSMapView with the camera position.
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    [mapView_ setMinZoom:5 maxZoom:19];

    NSLog(@"max zoom: %f", mapView_.maxZoom);
```

Comment: Thanks @ztan ... let me check it again. Maybe I did a mistake.

Comment: I posted the same issue again on think link.. Please check ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606375/ios-google-map-sdk-setting-maxzoom-level-issue-when-using-tiles